# How I can use regex to implement contains functionality?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

P.S : `If you don't understand anything from the below I describe, please ask me`

I have a Dictionary with the list of words. 
And I have String of one word with multiple characters.

Eg: Dictionary =>

```
String[] = {"Manager","age","range", "east".....} // list of words in dictionary
```

Now I have one string `tageranm`.

I have to find all the words in the dictionary  which can be made using this string. I have been able to find the solution using create all string using Permuation and verify the string is present in the dictionary.

But I have another solution, but dint know how I  can do it in Java using **Regex**

**Algorithm:**

---

```
// 1. Sort `tageranm`. 

char c[] = "tageranm".toCharArray();

Arrays.sort(c);

letters = String.valueOf(c); // letters = "aaegmnrt"

2.Sort all words in dictionary:

Example: "range"  => "aegnr"  // After sorting
```

Now If I will use `"aaegmnrt".contains("aegnr")` will return false. As `'m'` is coming in between.

Is there a way to use Regex and ignore the character `m` and get all the words in dictionary using the above approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "aaegmnrt".contains("a.*e.*g.*n.*r")...  but it's not gonna be fast

Comment: https://www.davepagurek.com/blog/scrabble-regular-expressions/

Comment: @Matt That's okay. I want to know how I can do this using the approach I have thought.

Comment: Is the order of characters important? How about repeating chars? Should `ego` be matched with `oge`? Or should `oo` be matched with `oge`?

Comment: I asked about four questions please be more compassionate about answering them.

Comment: Try `pattern = s.replaceAll(".(?=(.))", "$0[^$1]*")` (it will make `a[^e]*e[^g]*g[^n]*n[^r]*r` out of `aegnr`) and then `Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(str).find()` to look for a partial match. Well, probably just inserting `.*` between the chars will be better, see top comment.

Comment: @Wiktor It doesn't match. Return `false`.

Comment: @revo. Order of the characters is important. If there are repeating characters , it should be repeated in both words. Ego can't be matched with oge. oo can't be matched with oge.

Comment: @Nicky Please share the code you are using to test the pattern.

Comment: String regex = "aegnr".replaceAll(".(?=(.))", "$0[^$1]*");
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("aaegmnrt");
  System.out.println(matcher.find());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, using the regex-type stated by [*@MattTimmermans* in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967602/how-i-can-use-regex-to-implement-contains-functionality#comment88931613_50967602). It's not very fast though, so there are probably loads of ways to improve this.. I'm also pretty sure there should be libraries for this kind of searches, which will (hopefully) have used performance-reducing algorithms.

```
java.util.List<String> test(String[] words, String input){
  java.util.List<String> result = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

  // Sort the characters in the input-String:
  byte[] inputArray = input.getBytes();
  java.util.Arrays.sort(inputArray);
  String sortedInput = new String(inputArray);

  for(String word : words){
    // Sort the characters of the word:
    byte[] wordArray = word.getBytes();
    java.util.Arrays.sort(wordArray);
    String sortedWord = new String(wordArray);

    // Create a regex to match from this word:
    String wordRegex = ".*" + sortedWord.replaceAll(".", "$0.*");
    // If the input matches this regex:
    if(sortedInput.matches(wordRegex))
      // Add the word to the result-List:
      result.add(word);
  }

  return result;
}
```

[Try it online (with added DEBUG-lines to see what's happening).](https://tio.run/##jVNNT4NAEL33V0w2HsDWjef6kbTRGBN7sTEejIctbJEKC9kdWpumvx33C0q1RC8sw7z3Zt4DVmzNLlbxZ11HGVMKZiwVuwFAWS2yNAKFDPWxLtIYct0K5ihTkby9AwsNDCwBcrgBwTe2CMIr25hvFfKcFhXSUnMwE0FOkSsMDLLR2ZEZEyzhkoyIPvRVMmFOIJwpJHt9g6bPRE5CK70f6MtK700rTDP6lCq8dnK3YPXbHTeFjNXIz4JUlBX6rXvokqsqQ2/mgJlIybYWeGvc9dkjd/fTl4exGzQGMnQTXRyLLXK9kn1k9fQUW9CE41Q3VRPcj7mKqkJicCA2@TpXpsnjR9P1e7vGCUL/xh0Rs3enbOwuC@lztanC2IXr42ztmYeNO3P/y1yfvZbY4o78vZqZR/ZOEP7yZ0QO9kzVco9nGu1nnvAvPZLQcwLDjgKVvMxYxCdZFhBqPtSzS435zxqtrtmiLVpmugw6ydOcYfShkzsAQw8E/6FSFse27SX27l1JjpUUHuP@mH1dfwM)

For your inputs `{"Manager","age","range", "east"}` and `"tageranm"` it will return `["age", "range"]`.

EDIT: Doesn't match `Manager` because the `M` is in uppercase. If you want case-insensitive matching, the easiest it to convert both the input and words to the same case before checking:

- `input.getBytes()` becomes `input.toLowerCase().getBytes()`
- `word.getBytes()` becomes `word.toLowerCase().getBytes()`

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jVNNTwIxEL37KyaNh13BxjMqCagxJnCRGA/GQ2HLurjbJe0sSMj@9rVfW8BA8NLudN68eW/aXbAVu14k300zy5lSMGaZ2F4ALKtpns1AIUO9rcosgUKnognKTKQfn8BiAwNbAAXcg@BrG0TxrU1MNgp5QcsK6VLXYC6igiJXGBlky7MlYyZYyiXpEr3pVTJhdiCcKSS1/kCTZ6IgsaWuL/Sy0LpphVlOR5nCO0fXB8sfNK5Lmaiu7wWZWFboVZ8ol1xVOXozO8xASraxwL5xd8oeeXwavj33XKMekI7r6MYx3SDXkuyR5dNdbECxHJVrLh@Y4lFMU45DDVXtGP@oUFSVEqMdTTtt59EkefJist6FSxwpOK1/j8S42Atb8/NS@inbGUPPjdoPN5g1h61X833G6imzgSbgDty@GwUHZo8UnHNrSHZmTRRqD3sa7lee8h/dktArAp09Bir5MmczPsjziFDziC9vNOY/MgKvURGCUJnNo717oAXD2Zee3A4YeyD4R0xZkti0p6jdzUmOlRQe4/6muml@AQ) (now resulting in `["Manager", "age", "range"]`).

Comment: For my problem statement, it should return `manager` and `east` as well. As we can make those words also from `tageranm`

Comment: @Nicky I can't make `Manager` nor `east` with the letters from `tageranm` (`M` is capital instead of lowercase, and it doesn't contain a `s`). I can fix the case-insensitive part if you'd like so it does match `Manager`, but creating `east` from the letters `tageranm` is not possible.

Comment: I am sorry `east` won't be but manager can be. Yeah , case sensitivity is not important. Apologies for creating confusion

Comment: If you want to match `Manager` out of  `tageranm` it means order of characters are not important. You are just looking for existence of letters. @Nicky

Comment: @Nicky I've added an edit at the bottom to also match `Manager`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the solution. I had to made one more change. Add `.*` in the start of the wordRegex also. I have used string concatantion. Any other better way ?

Comment: @Nicky Ah, you're right. The regex mentioned in the comments are using contains / Pattern which only try to match part of the regex, while the `String.matches` I use implicitly add a leading `^` and a trailing `$` to see if the entire string matches the regex, so the leading `.*` should indeed be added. My bad..

Comment: @Kevin Could you explain me this please. `sortedWord.replaceAll(".", "$0.*");` What does `.` means in 1st arg and $0 means in the second argument?

Comment: @Nicky A dot `.` is a wildcard in regexes for any single character. This single character will be replaced with: `$0`: the entire match itself (the character in this case) appended with a literal `.*` (which in itself means any single character (`.`) repeated zero or more times (`*`). Alternatively, `.replaceAll("(.)", "$1.*")` could be used, where `(.)` still matches a single character, which we capture in a group, and the `$1` will then be used to copy this first (and only in this case) group. [Here a Java regex tutorial.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)